# Battery Usage in Windows 11

Tags: laptop, battery, windows-11, battery-life

If I navigate to **Systems > Power & Battery** in Settings, and then down to the **Battery Usage** section, there should be a section that shows the Battery Usage per Application. Unfortunately, on my Dell XPS laptop, this section is always empty (shows *No apps used battery during this time period*) despite me using a number of apps during that time period and the battery dropping (quite considerably at times).

[image: Screenshot of Battery Usage section]

How do I get this feature working so that I can see what is using up my battery?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's it, as I've previously had it unplugged for a few hours without it showing anything there (just not when I took this screenshot).

Comment: Have a look in Task Manager, Processes tab, and look at the Power usage and Power usage trend columns. Do you see the power data?

Comment: Yes, it has "Low" and "Very Low" in there at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by a firmware update, so was presumably an issue with the laptop firmware rather than Windows 11.